# PHP Setup with Zend Server and Apache - Win 7

Tags: php, apache, apache2, zend-server

I've installed:  Zend Server 6.0  --  Apache 2.2.22  --  Zend Studio 9.0.3

All located in their own sub-folders, inside *C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend*

---

**4 line test script**

```
<php
    echo phpinfo();
?>
hello
```

---

When I go to: *localhost:10081*

I am directed to a file located at *C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\public\index.php*

The PHP file has my 4-line test... and it executes as expected

---

When i go to: *127.0.0.1*

I am directed to a file located at *C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\index.php*

This PHP file also has the same 4 line test, but only ouputs 'hello'.

---

When I edit the index.php files to have a PHP error, Zend Server only logs the error from the index.php file inside \ZendServer\gui\public.

I would like to have my local web application reside inside \Apache2\htdocs\

How can I accomplish this?  I can provide any other information necessary to assist.

Thank you!

~~~~ **edit** ~~~~

Here are various files which may be necessary pieces of information.  Or, they may just be excessive clutter to this post so I will keep them at the bottom.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\conf\zend.conf**

```
<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location> 

LoadModule zend_enabler_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\ZendEnablerApache.dll"
ZendEnablerConfig "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\etc\ZendEnablerConf.xml"
AddHandler zend-enabler-script .php 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php   

<Location /phpMyAdmin>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Location>

Alias /phpMyAdmin "__HTTPD_PHPMYADMIN_PATH__"


Listen 10081
AllowEncodedSlashes On
Win32DisableAcceptEx

NameVirtualHost *:10081
<VirtualHost *:10081>
Alias /ZendServer "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\public"
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\public"
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/$ /ZendServer/ [R]
RewriteRule ^/Login$ /ZendServer/Login [R]
  <Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\gui\public">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


Listen 10083
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:10083
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:10083>
CustomLog "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\logs\access.log" common env=logme
Alias /UserServer "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\UserServer"
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\UserServer"
  <Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\UserServer">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your code is broken. `<?php` is the opening tag and you don't need to echo `phpinfo()`.

Comment: -.-    how stinkin rediculous! thank you, i can't believe i missed that!  Now I just need to determine how to get Zend Server to recognize this location and show that as an error in the log...

Comment: Disregard that too... now that I have the PHP code recognized with the fix you caught, zend server catches the errors too! thanks!

Comment: I dont think you can. Without the correct php open tag, it just handles the code as text.

Comment: @datasage do you want to post this as an answer or should i just delete the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php code is broken. The open tag has to be `<?php`. Echo on phpinfo is redundant since phpinfo outputs directly and does not return anything.